# how to solve camera and storege files permissions on real device with flutter

Tags: flutter, permissions, camera, storage, dart-html

I have this code it's work on emulator, but on real device return error 500 from the server because the real device dont send camera images files to the server
the images taken by camera and loaded to the device normally on both of emeulator and real device but it's cant been sent from real device.
here is the code for take image

```
 List<File> takenImagesList = <File>[];

  // ignore: missing_return
  Future<File> getImageToList() async {
    // ignore: deprecated_member_use
    final oneImage = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    setState(() {
      // ignore: unrelated_type_equality_checks
      if (oneImage == null || oneImage == "null") {
      } else
        takenImagesList.add(oneImage);
    });
  }
```

and this is the api

```
 Future<bool> imageOrder({
    @required BuildContext context,
    // @required Item item,
    @required String gov,
    @required String address,
    @required String lat,
    @required String lng,
    @required String note,
    @required List<File> takenImagesList,
  }) async {
    print("imageOrder");
    bool status;
    var headers = {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Cookie': 'lang=${getTranslated(context, "language")}',
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      'Authorization': tokenPublic,
    };
    print(serverAPILink);
    var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse(serverAPILink));
    request.fields.addAll({
      'action[0]': 'Order',
      'action[1]': 'store',
      'is_prescription': '1',
      'province': '$gov',
      'address': '$address',
      'lat': '$lat',
      'lng': '$lng',
      'notes': '$note'
    });
    for (int i = 0; i < takenImagesList.length; i++) {
      request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(
          'files[$i]', takenImagesList[i].path));
      print(i);
    }
    print("request.files.length=>${request.files.length}");
    request.headers.addAll(headers);
    print("headers=>$headers");
    print("request.files=>${request.files}");

    http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var responseBody = jsonDecode(await response.stream.bytesToString());
      print("responseBody => $responseBody");
      if (responseBody['success'] == true) {
        print("order done");
        status = true;
      } else if (responseBody['success'] == false) {
        status = false;
        myAlertShow(context: context, responseBody: responseBody);
        myAlertShow(context: context, responseBody: response.reasonPhrase);
        return status;
      }
    } else if (response.statusCode == 401) {
      logOutMethod(context: context);
      status = false;
    } else {
      print("response.statusCode ${response.statusCode}");
      print("response.reasonPhrase :=> ${response.reasonPhrase}");
      print(response.reasonPhrase);
    }
    return status;
  }
```

it's work on emulator and this is log

```
I/flutter (24893): request.files.length=>3
I/flutter (24893): headers=>{Accept: application/json, Cookie: lang=ar, Content-Type: multipart/form-data, Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJ****
I/flutter (24893): request.files=>[Instance of 'MultipartFile', Instance of 'MultipartFile', Instance of 'MultipartFile']
I/flutter (24893): responseBody => {success: true, data: {is_prescription: true, province: بغداد, address: aaaaaaaaaaa, lat: 3****, lng: -1*****, notes: bbbbbbbbbbb, updated_at: 2021-05-11 2:54 PM, created_at: 2021-05-11 2:54 PM, id: 160}}
I/flutter (24893): order done
I/flutter (24893): stut=true
```

as you see it's work , but the problem is on the real device,it's didn't work,and here is the log

```
I/flutter (10667): request.files.length=>3
I/flutter (10667): headers=>{Accept: application/json, Cookie: lang=ar, Content-Type: multipart/form-data, Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiO*****
I/flutter (10667): request.files=>[Instance of 'MultipartFile', Instance of 'MultipartFile', Instance of 'MultipartFile']
I/flutter (10667): response.statusCode 500
I/flutter (10667): response.reasonPhrase :=> Internal Server Error
I/flutter (10667): Internal Server Error
I/flutter (10667): stut=null
```

Answer (score 0):

I think when you get 500, it actually crashes, so u need to do sth like

```
try {
      var response = await http...;
      if (response.statusCode == 200)
        ...
    } catch(e,s){
//do sth
    }
```

or u can catch error by error

`on SocketException {` ...

Comment: can you explain more please?

Comment: error: A try block must be followed by an 'on', 'catch', or 'finally' clause. (missing_catch_or_finally at [plaster] lib\Api\MakeNewOrderApi.dart:114)

Comment: @Husamuldeen you can take a look here to understand exception handling 

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/dart_programming/dart_programming_exceptions.htm

Comment: after searching I found that the real device dont upload the files, I gues it's Permission cause that, so do you know how to add the camera and storege permissions?

Answer (score 0):

add this line

```
android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES"/>
```

to android > manifest file.

Comment: i did this already and still the same, for now I changed the
```
    final oneImage = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
```
to gallary
```
    final oneImage = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallary);
```